# How to aggregate results from multiple JMeter servers

Tags: jmeter

I wish to run multiple JMeter servers on various machines to ramp-up volumes but in the end wish to see aggregated values from all servers in my graphs and plots.

From what I understand each server will produce it's own results though, so if I have each machine/server running 500 concurrent users and lets say I have 5 of the machines running, how do I get to aggregate the 2500 total concurrent user responses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JMeter Remote testing, slave machines will just run the test and send the report to the master machine.

Follow these steps:

1. Collect the results file(.jtl) from the master machine.
2. Open the JMeter GUI and then add a listener like [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) or [Aggregate Graph](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Graph) in your test plan.
3. Now, Open your collected results file using Browse button through that listener.

Comment: Thank you @Jahan. I am using jp@gc graphs to monitor progress within the GUI. Will I not be able to see the progress when running on remote servers? Do I need to wait for the tests to complete before I see something? I have added the Aggregate Report and pointed it to the results.jtl file and set all the other Listeners to the same results file but I get nothing. Could you possibly elaborate with a more precise example/steps or a link to a tutorial?

Comment: PS: I am also using an Access Log Sampler to set the test run, where should the log file be considering I get an error on the remote machine that it couldn't parse it (assuming it means it cant find the file). I am running on two Mac, two Ubuntu and one Windows machine.

Comment: Yes, you have to wait for the test complete. JMeter listeners are too heavy since it consumes too much memory. So, you have to run the test in Non-GUI mode (do not add any listeners in your test plan when you perform your load test) and then collect your results file after the test has done and then you can analyze the report in GUI (add any listener in your test plan to analyze) mode. Thank you!